# Wordpress 3.0 Media Upload Directory

Tags: media, directory, media-library

I am using Wordpress 3.0 and would like to organize the directory where uploads are made. Is there any way to change where the files get uploaded or is the only real organization the Media tag plugin?

What would be ideal is when a user uploads a file, they can specify a sub directory where to dump the file (or default to date). So a user could say "flowers" and the file would go in uploads/flowers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see if [Custom Upload Dir (Wordpress Plugin)](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-upload-dir/) does the job for you. With that plugin you can configure the upload path based on numerous settings.